# Migrate Spring Security 2.0.5 to Spring Security 3.0.8 Not working on Weblogic with F5 Load balancer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, weblogic12c

We are trying to migrate the Spring Security 2.0.5 to 3.0.8.  Changes are working in Tomcat and Weblogic Server with SSL enabled but no F5 Load balancer. But when deployed application on Weblogic 12.c with two Nodes in it and having F5 Load balancer, it started failing. Before this deployment application was working good, but after this deployment it behaving weirdly. On IE , login button throws error as "Network Error" and sometimes SSL error and on chrome , you can login but page is getting stuck . Can any body please help. 
Here are the changes

**applicationContext-security.xml (2.0.5)**

```
 1. <global-method-security />


 2. <intercept-url pattern="/bs/systemCheck.action" filters="none" 
                          access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
 3. <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" 
                            class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
             <beans:property name="providers">
                      <beans:list>
                           <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
                   </beans:list>
              </beans:property>
     </beans:bean>
```

**applicationContext-security.xml (3.0.8)**

```
 1.  <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured- 
                           annotations="enabled"/>
 2.  <intercept-url pattern="/bs/systemCheck.action" filters="none"/>

 3.  <beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
                                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
                     <beans:property name="providers">
                                <beans:list>
                               <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
                                    </beans:list>
                     </beans:property>
     </beans:bean>
 4.  <custom-filter ref="logoutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
           <custom-filter ref="authenticationProcessingFilter" 
                                    position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
           <custom-filter ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER"/>

 5. <!-- Protects against session fixation  - 
                                defaulting to new session & migrate session-->
          <session-management session-authentication-strategy-
                               ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"/>
                   <beans:property name="basicStructureManager" 
                                       ref="basicStructureManager"/>
                   <beans:property name="accountManager" ref="accountManager" />
                                    <!-- Note - this is very important otherwise we get response 
                               committed issue-->

               <beans:property name="continueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication" 
                                  value="false" />

 6. <beans:bean id="successHandler" 
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/bs/home.action"/>
            <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
        </beans:bean>
 7. <beans:bean id="failureHandler" 
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
         <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/bs/login.action?loginError=1"/>
        </beans:bean>
```

And in web.xml added

```
<!-- Required by Spring security to handle session strategy -->

<listener>
         <listener-class>
                org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
         </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly and show the diffrences between the different versions. Currently it is more of a puzzle then information.

Comment: These are just snippets so quite hard to figure out I would say. Is there a reason why you configure the `successHandler` and `failureHandler` instead of using the `<login-form >` element in your http block?

Comment: Use of this "successHandler" and "failureHandler". to handle the Login failure to redirect based on sucess or failure and we are using this in Filters.

Comment: This is why there are attributes like `success-url` and `authentication-failure-url` on the `login-form` element.

Comment: Yes, but It is not a filter that we want to use that across the app. But is it related to Web logic not working properly

Comment: I wonder why you configure a lot of things by hand that might be configured by the namespace. But we would probably have to see your full security setup and some logging (put `org.springframework.security` on  `DEBUG` or `TRACE`) and see what happens. These snippets aren't helpful, at least not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem is totally different but showing different error message. Some code change happened, for that used "clone" on domain object(Which is a very big Object). So all the connections are occupied and there are no resource for new request.